# Gauss-Laguerre quadrature

Tags: numerical-methods, improper-integrals

I am trying to compute this integral:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\prod_{k = 1}^{d}\left(1 - \,\mathrm{e}^{-a_{k}\,t}\right)
\,\mathrm{e}^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t,\quad
\mbox{where}\quad a_{k} > 0, \forall\ k.
$$

I can compute this just fine for small values $d$, e.g., less than $100$, using a *numerical Gauss-Laguerre quadrature*. I am having trouble computing this accurately when $d$ gets larger.  Any suggestions on how to solve this problem ?.

Comment: do u have more informations on the $a_k$'s

Comment: By the change of variable $x=e^{-t}$ you are lead to integrate this 'polynomial' function: $ \int_0 ^1 \prod_{k=1}^d (1 - x^{a_k} ) dx$ which might be easier.

Comment: Yes.  They are of the form:  $$a_k = r_k / \sum_{j=d+1}^n r_j ,$$ where $r_k, r_j > 0.$  Not sure how helpful this would be.

Comment: I too thought of the variable transformation, but I don't think it would help.

Comment: are they decreaing?

Comment: No.  There is no pattern.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> With $\ds{a_{k} > 0\,,\ \forall\ k \in \braces{1,2,\ldots,d}}$:

\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{\infty}\prod_{k = 1}^{d}\pars{1 - \expo{-a_{k}\,t}}
\expo{-t}\,\dd t} =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\prod_{k = 1}^{d}
\pars{a_{k}t\int_{0}^{1}\expo{-a_{k}\,t\,x_{k}}\,\dd x_{k}}\expo{-t}\,\dd t
\\[3mm] = &\
\pars{\prod_{k = 1}^{d}a_{k}}
\int_{0}^{1}\cdots\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{d}
\exp\pars{-\bracks{\sum_{j = 1}^{d}a_{j}x_{j} + 1}t}\,\dd t
\,\prod_{k = 1}^{d}\dd x_{k}
\\[3mm] = &\
\Gamma\pars{d + 1}\pars{\prod_{k = 1}^{d}a_{k}}\,\mathrm{f}_{d}\pars{\vec{a}}
\tag{1}
\\[5mm] &\ \mbox{where}\
\,\mathrm{f}_{d}\pars{\vec{a}} \equiv
\int_{0}^{1}\cdots\int_{0}^{1}
{\prod_{k = 1}^{d}\,\dd x_{k} \over \pars{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{x} + 1}^{d + 1}}
\\[2mm] & \mbox{and}\quad
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\vec{a}} & \ds{\equiv} & \ds{\pars{a_{1},a_{2}\,\ldots,a_{d}}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\vec{x}} &  \ds{\equiv} &  \ds{\pars{x_{1},x_{2}\,\ldots,x_{d}}}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

---

It's still a 'hard' one. However, when $\ds{d}$ is 'very large' the main contribution arises 'from' $\ds{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{x} \gtrsim 0}$ such that
\begin{align}
\,\mathrm{f}_{d}\pars{\vec{a}} & \sim
\int_{0}^{1}\cdots\int_{0}^{1}
\exp\pars{-\bracks{d + 1}\vec{a}\cdot\vec{x}}
\prod_{k = 1}^{d}\,\dd x_{k}
\\[5mm] & =
\prod_{k = 1}^{d}\int_{0}^{1}
\exp\pars{-\bracks{d + 1}a_{k}x_{k}}\,\dd x_{k} =
\prod_{k = 1}^{d}{1 - \expo{-\pars{d + 1}a_{k}} \over \pars{d + 1}a_{k}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over \pars{d + 1}^{d}}
\prod_{k = 1}^{d}{1 - \expo{-\pars{d + 1}a_{k}} \over a_{k}}
\end{align}
and $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{see expression}\ \pars{1}~}}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{\infty}\prod_{k = 1}^{d}\pars{1 - \expo{-a_{k}\,t}}
\expo{-t}\,\dd t}
\\[3mm] \sim &\
\root{2\pi}d^{d + 1/2}\,\,\expo{-d}\pars{\prod_{k = 1}^{d}a_{k}}
{1 \over \pars{d + 1}^{d}}
\prod_{k = 1}^{d}{1 - \expo{-\pars{d + 1}a_{k}} \over a_{k}}\tag{2}
\\[3mm] & =
\root{2\pi}d^{1/2}{1 \over \pars{1 + 1/d}^{d}}\,\expo{-d} \sim
\color{#f00}{\root{2\pi}d^{1/2}\expo{-\pars{d + 1}}}
\end{align}

> Note that
>   $$
> \bracks{1 - \expo{-\pars{d + 1}\min\braces{a_{k}}}\,\,}^{d} <
> \prod_{k = 1}^{d}\bracks{1 - \expo{-\pars{d + 1}a_{k}}} <
> \bracks{1 - \expo{-\pars{d + 1}\max\braces{a_{k}}}\,\,}^{d}
> $$

Comment: I am surprised that $a_k$ are not involved in your final approximation.  Could this be correct?

Comment: @Ravi I was surprised too. However, one line before ( see expression $\left(2\right)$ ) we see a remaining dependence on $\left\{a_{k}\right\}$ as
$$
\sqrt{2\pi}\, d^{1/2}\,\,\mathrm{e}^{-2d}\,\,\prod_{k = 1}^{d}\left[1 - \,\mathrm{e}^{-\left(d + 1\right)a_{k}}\,\,\,\right]
$$

Comment: I think there is a mistake. $(1 + 1/d)^d \approx e$ hence the $e^{-2d}$ term should actually be $e^{-(d+1)}$.  Right?

Comment: @Ravi Thanks. You are right. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Let we exploit $\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-kx}\,dx=\frac{1}{k}$ by expanding the product:

$$ I(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_d)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x}\prod_{k=1}^{d}\left(1-e^{-\alpha_k x}\right)\,dx \\= 1-\sum_{k=1}^{d}\frac{1}{\alpha_k+1}+\sum_{1\leq k_1<k_2\leq d}\frac{1}{\alpha_{k_1}+\alpha_{k_2}+1}-\ldots+(-1)^d\frac{1}{\alpha_1+\ldots+\alpha_d+1}\\=\color{blue}{\int_{0}^{1}\prod_{k=1}^{d}\left(1-x^{\alpha_k}\right)\,dx}$$
the last integral does not have a nice general closed form, but it is easy to approximate through [Holder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality), since [Euler's beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) gives:

$$ \int_{0}^{1}(1-x^{\alpha})^p\,dx = \frac{\Gamma(p+1)\,\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{a}\right)}{\Gamma\left(p+1+\frac{1}{a}\right)}.$$

Comment: Jack, thanks for the comment, but it still doesn't help me. I don't know how to approximate and make use of Euler's beta function.

Comment: For example, I could take $\alpha_{min} = min(\alpha_k)$ and $\alpha_{max} = max(\alpha_k)$, and bound the integral using Euler's beta function at max and min, right?  Not sure though how accurate that is going to be.

Comment: @Ravi: there is no need to take $\max$ or $\min$, just use the generalized Holder's inequality by leaving the exponents as they are.

Comment: I think generalized Holder is going to give me a loose upper bound. I am afraid it may not be sufficiently accurate.

Comment: @Ravi: I cannot say since I do not know what you precision goals are, but Cauchy Schwarz and Holder's inequalities tend to give pretty accurate approximations, hard to do better with elementary means. Is something else known about the $\alpha_k$? Maybe they form an arithmetic progression?

Comment: If I want to apply generalized Holder, how would I choose the exponents for the upper bounding RHS?  Would the obvious choice $1/d$ be the best?

Comment: @Ravi: you may try equals exponents, exponents proportional to $\alpha$ or exponents proportional to $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ and check which inequality is better.

Answer (score 1):

The large number of factors will make the integrand look like a Gaussian near its peak. The maximum of the integrand is at $t = t^*$ satisfying the equation:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{d} \frac{a_j}{\exp(a_j t^*)-1} = 1$$

The second derivative of the logarithm of the integrand at the maximum is $-\sigma$ with

$$\sigma = \sum_{j=1}^{d} \frac{a_j^2\exp(a_j t^*)}{\left[\exp(a_j t^*)-1\right]^2}$$

The integrand near its peak is then approximately proportional to $\exp\left[-\frac{\sigma}{2}\left(t-t^*\right)^2\right]$. Using the values for $t^*$ and $\sigma$, you can set up an optimal Gauss-Hermite quadrature scheme.

Comment: did you include $e^{-t}$ in the integrand?

Comment: @Ravi Yes, that's where the "1" on the left hand side of the first equation comes from (take the logarithm and set the derivative equal to zero). In the second derivative this term  vanishes.

Comment: In that case, why do we need Gauss-Hermite? The integral would be a Gaussian function, which can be written down analytically, right? Isn't this similar to the Laplace approximation for unimodal density functions?

Comment: @Ravi Yes, you can do that (e.g. by computing also the higher order terms and computing the higher order corrections too ), but you can also just stick to the numerical approach where you use the Gaussian form to improve the numerical computations. For large d the source of the problem is that the integrand becomes strongly peaked, this causes the Gauss-Laguerre method to miss the peak, yielding bad results.